# How to prevent table exceeding its div container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table inside a div (`.content`)

When I resize the screen and re-fresh, the schedule table is always wider than its container div.

I use Chrome F12 tools to debug it, add/remove css. I tried to put on padding-left/right but does not work, tried to shrink the font size, which does not work.

The table cells i.e. td seems not resize accordingly.

Here is the url : http://liferunningclub.com.au/

```css
/*schedule*/
.schedule {
  background: url('img/schedules.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align:center;
}

.schedule .content { padding:85px 0 95px; text-align:center;}
.schedule h2 { background:url(img/red-border.jpg) no-repeat center bottom !important; padding-bottom:22px; margin-bottom:55px;} 
.schedule .half { width:50%; margin:0 -3px 0 0; float:left}
.schedule table { width:100%}
.schedule table td { background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1); text-transform:uppercase; padding:12px; color:#fff;font-family: 'dinprolight'; font-size:20px; line-height:24px; width:33%}
.schedule table .first-row td { background:#e80f41}
.schedule table .second-row td { background:#c50f3c}
.schedule table .third-row td { background:#a60a31}
.schedule table td.empty {background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1) !important; } 
.schedule table thead td { font-size:24px;font-family: 'dinpro-black-webfont';}
.schedule table td span { display:block;font-family: 'dinpro-black-webfont';}

.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; *zoom: 1}
.clearfix { display: inline-block}
.clear { clear:both; line-height:0; height:1px; font-size:0}
html[xmlns] .clearfix { display: block}
* html .clearfix {height: 1%}


/*medium*/
@media screen and (min-width: 730px) and (max-width: 960px) {

.content .clearfix { padding-left: 20px!important; padding-right: 20px!important; }

.schedule .half { float: none; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px }

.half { width: 100%; float: none; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }
}

/*small*/
@media screen and (max-width: 729px) {

.content .clearfix { padding-left: 20px!important; padding-right: 20px!important; }

.schedule .half { float: none; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px }

.schedule .content { padding: 60px 0; }

.half { width: 100%; float: none; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }

    .schedule td p {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

/*end of schedule*/
```

```html
<div class="schedule" id="schedule">
    <div class="content clearfix">
        <h2>SCHEDULE</h2>

        <div class="half">
            <table style="width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="3">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row">Monday</td>
                        <td>Tuesday</td>
                        <td>Wednesday</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="first-row">
                        <td scope="row">
                            <p>
                                6:30AM <span>ESSENDON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                6:30AM <span>CARLTON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                6:30AM <span>ESSENDON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="second-row">
                        <td scope="row">
                            <p>
                                5:15PM<span>CARLTON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                6:00PM<span>ESSENDON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                5:15PM<span>CARLTON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="third-row">
                        <td scope="row">
                            <p>
                                6:00PM<span>CARLTON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="empty"></td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                6:00PM<span>CARLTON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="half">
            <table style="width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="3">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Thursday</td>
                        <td>Friday</td>
                        <td>Saturday</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="first-row">
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                6:30AM <span>CARLTON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                6:30AM <span>ESSENDON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                8:15AM <span>ESSENDON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="second-row">
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                8:15AM<span>ESSENDON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="empty"></td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                10:00AM<span>CARLTON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="third-row">
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                6:00PM<span>ESSENDON</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="empty"></td>
                        <td class="empty"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### **How to reproduce the issue**

Simply resizing the window will not trigger the issue. What I do to trigger it is

1. open it with your real mobile devices or,
2. If you are using Chrome, F12 then click the Mobile mode and choose a small screen mobile, AND press Ctrl + F5 to refresh the page

   If you are using Firefox, press F12 then click the "Responsive Design Mode" AND press Ctrl + F5 to refresh the page.

Here is what it will look like in Chrome and Firefox.

[image]

Comment: The demo runs fine to me, what is the issue?

Comment: @Pangloss It seems to run fine for me as well.

Comment: hi @Pangloss please see my update 1 abt how to reproduce the issue, thank you :)

Comment: hi @Blkc please see my update 1 abt how to reproduce the issue, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the titles within `th`. You need to reduce the `font-size` of th

Something like this should help:

```
.schedule table thead td{
 font-size:18px;
}
```

Comment: you are absolutely amazing~! how did you find it? this is more important after the problem is solved, please let me know, thx :)

Comment: When you resize, after a certain point, the width of the text/word prevents the td from contracting further. One option is to use word-break:break-all; to break the word so that the excess letters move to the next line.

From the design perspective, that might look weird. So the next best option is to reduce the font-size.